# kotlin synthetic Integer cannot be cast to floating button

Tags: casting, kotlin, floating-action-button

Why does

`val fabOpen = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_open) as FloatingActionButton`

work correctly and not error out but the kotlin synthetic of

`val fabOpen = R.id.fab_open as FloatingActionButton`

gives me the

`java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`

error?  They both show that they are casting as `FloatingActionButton`.  Using the synthetics is not only less code, it's better memory management and I'd prefer to do it this way.  Is there something I am missing?

****Update****  I forgot to mention I am trying access the `FloatingActionButton` inside of a fragment if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.id.fab_open` is a generated integer value that will be set as the ID of your button at inflation, and that you can look up with `findViewById` like you've shown.

Casting this to a button won't work, think `(FloatingActionButton) 2688664731` in Java terms.

If you wish to use [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#view-binding) and its synthetic properties, those are simply named as the ID itself, but they don't come from the `R` class - and you don't need to assign them to variables or properties. You can simply use your button like this:

```
fab_open.setOnClickListener { ... }
fab_open.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

Comment: Because this is a fragment, I needed to add `view.` first.

Comment: You actually don't, Extensions will do that part for you as well. You do need the Fragment's View to be already set though - I recommend doing your initialization in `onViewCreated` instead of in `onCreateView`.

Comment: I actually do need it to be `view.fab_open.setOnClickListener { ... }` in order to access the FAB.  Look at my code.  I am inflating the fragment's view into the Val `view`.  So to access the `ID`, I need to access the fragment's View which is `view.`  Otherwise, it cannot access the `ID` because it cannot access the view.

Comment: Also, by using the Kotlin Synthetic, it casts the type for me, I don't have to do `as FloatingActionButton`.  It knows that it's a floating action button.  That's the beauty of Kotlin synthetics. 'view.fab_open.visibility = "visible"` is the same as `Val fabOpen = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_open) as FloatingActionButton fabOpen.visibility = "visible"`

Comment: Also, why the recommendation to put initializations in `onViewCreated` instead of `onCreateView`?  What's the advantage?

Comment: Just try putting the code sample I gave in my answer in `onViewCreated`, it will work without prefixing everything with `view.`. This can be done because by this point in the lifecycle, you've aleady returned the created `View` to the `Fragment`, and it can access it automatically from there. You only have to do `view.` if you're setting up your Views before it's been set to the `Fragment`.

Comment: Now I understand.  Sorry if I sounded crass, that wasn't my intention.  I reread what I wrote.  I wasn't thinking about the lifecycle.  I will definitely check on moving things into `onViewCreated`.  While my solution does work, I think yours is leaner.

Comment: I'm just glad I've managed to explain what's happening! Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue.

to access an element in a view using kotlin synthetic it looks like this:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.chatter_main.view.*

class ChatterMain : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatter_main, container, false)

return view
}
```

Above I imported the kotlin synthetic of the view, inflated the view, and
then I accessed the ID of the element like this:

`view.fab_open.visibility = GONE` or `view.fab_open.SetOnClickListener {}`

With the Kotlin Synthetic, you don't need to use:

`val fabOpen = R.id.fab_open as FloatingActionButton` so I removed that statement.